# How to locate the element by using dynamic x-path for link?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I am trying to find the element using Dynamic x path but my code is not working for the element

```
<a href="/corporate-checkups/our-corporate-services.html" class="has-submenu" id="sm-15547263985364824-1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="sm-15547263985364824-2" aria-expanded="false"><span class="sub-arrow">+</span>Our Services</a>
```

Want to select sub-menu by using Action class but here i am unable to locate the element

Comment: Please provide your html code and error stack trace

Comment: @SurajsinghAutoQA What exactly do you mean by _...select sub-menu by using Action class..._? `select` -> `click()`?? `sub-menu` = `+`??? Is `Action` class mandatory????

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the *sub-menu* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) (*Java Solution*):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.has-submenu[href='/corporate-checkups/our-corporate-services.html']>span.sub-arrow")).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='has-submenu' and @href='/corporate-checkups/our-corporate-services.html']/span[@class='sub-arrow']")).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Basically your locator its a link so you have to very simple options :

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(“Element LINKTEXT”));

driver.findElement(By.LinkText(“Element LINKTEXT”));
```

Choose which one you think works better for you.